# Any Free Integrated Code Coverage Tools for VS2010 (Professional Edition)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

Does anyone know of any free (critical point I'm afraid) code coverage tools for Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition. I know there are commercial offerings such as NCover and DotCover, but due to budget considerations these can't be considered.  For similar reasons, upgrading to versions of VS that come with code coverage built in also can't be considered.

Looking around I see there appears to be loads of free options for Java developers, but there doesn't appear to be any (VS integrated) options for .NET developers.  Please note that I am looking for VS integrated solutions.  I know there is a free community version of NCover that runs from the command line, but only the commercial edition is integrated with the VS IDE.

**Edit:** If no one is really aware of any free tools currently available, could anyone provide pointers to tutorials on how to create VS plug-ins that decorate code in the source window?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616977/whats-a-good-code-coverage-tool-for-use-with-visual-studio-c

Comment: @blueberryfields: No I hadn't found that one when I was searching yesterday.  I am looking for C# coverage tools and that's talking about C++, but I see there's some cross over in the answers to that question - I'll take a look at the products later.  If any of them are suitable I'll let you know and if you add your comment as an answer I'll give it the tick.  Thanks

Comment: Do you want code decorated with coverage data in *any* viewer, or do insist that it be integrated into the IDE?  I have to admit some puzzlement at the insistence on "free" but the apparant willingness to invest a bunch of time on implementing a plug-in.  If you are doing this for a commercial task, your time isn't free and commercial tools will cost less than your effort.

Comment: @Ira: Every point you raise about cost / ROI is valid, but I'm in the situation where it is free or nothing - there just isn't the money for this.   The plug-in was just something that I was thinking about after asking this question originally and would be a personal project.

Comment: Really, a question with 5 up votes  closed as off-topic nearly 5 years later; if it was - where we you in 2010!!!!

Answer (score 0):

partcover?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360/can-you-recommend-an-alternative-for-ncover

Comment: Thanks for the link, but looking at the site it is no longer being supported.  We are now using a paid for application to provide code coverage (managed to sell the business on the benefits over the cost)

Comment: The linked question no longer exists.